# Unable to open old mongodb Datafiles

Tags: mongodb

OS - Windows
Mongod version - 3.4
Storage Engine - mmapv1
I am unable to view old mongodb files .. 
I have an old dataset (1gb)
I tried opening the mongod server with mmapv1 as storage engine. The server starts and when I open my compass and view the files, the datafiles space shows 1 GB but when I open the file it has no documents. It has only 2 datafiles with no document size.
 
When I looked into the server log it only opens .0 and .1 files instead of all the files. My database have files from *.0 to *.5.
 
I guess this is the problem.
I tried mongodump but it crashes the server. 
I also tried downgrading my mongod version but same problem 
is it possible to recover the data?

Comment: MMAPv1 files don't shrink when data is deleted.  If the old dataset had 1GB of data at one point, but all of the documents were removed, it would still be at least 1GB of files.  If loading the files using the version of the program that created them doesn't work, the source code is available so you can see what format the files should be - try to read the bytes.

Comment: hi joe ,
the files are of the size 16mb , 32mb,64 mb (*.0, *.1,*.2.....). and so on till *.5  with size 524mb .
and a ns file of 16mb size